# Case sObject ContactEmail Standard Field Before Insert Trigger

Tags: case, before-trigger

Is the ContactEmail standard field on the Case sObject a "formula" field?

I plan to reference it during a before insert trigger, I am suspicious it shall not populated during a before insert trigger.

Per the official documentation: "The Case.ContactEmail field displays the Email field on the contact that is **referenced** by Case.ContactId. Label is Contact Email."

When I view the Case sObject metadata the field shows up as an email type.

Comment: No, it should be a lookup.

Comment: FYI the `SObject` class has a `recalculateFormulas()` method, though I don't think it works cross-object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this field is null *before insert*. This happens because formulas are only calculated when a record is loaded from the database. In a before insert, there's no data to load, so the field is null. It is available *after insert*, *before update*, etc.

Comment: But some formulas could be retrieved anyway in this trigger context, no?

Comment: @AdrianLarson No, the database isn't queried, so no formulas are populated. Also, just tested; `recalculateFormulas` in a before insert causes the following error: `System.UnexpectedException: Unable to create/update fields: IsDeleted, HasCommentsUnreadByOwner, IsClosed, IsClosedOnCreate, HasSelfServiceComments. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set.: Trigger.CaseContactEmail: line 2, column 1`

Comment: Ah, right, I've run into that before. Thanks for the refresher.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Ah, it's okay. I learned something new today.